# Run command automatically as root after login

Tags: login, root

I'm using evrouter to simulate keypresses from my mouses extra buttons. It works great but I need to run the command with sudo to make it work so I can't just use my DE to handle autostart.

I considered init.d but from what I've heard this only works for different stages of boot, and I need this to run as root *after* login.

```
$ cat .evrouterrc 
"Logitech G500" "/dev/input/event4" any key/277 "XKey/0"
"Logitech G500" "/dev/input/event4" any key/280 "XKey/9"
"Logitech G500" "/dev/input/event4" any key/281 "XKey/8"
$ sudo evrouter /dev/input/event4
```

**Edit:** Alrighty, it looks like I can use lightdm.conf's `session-setup-script` option to run a script as root. The script I have is below, but as expected when run as root the `id -u` no longer equals 1000 and the if statement never executes. Is there an argument or variable I can use to get the user name or id?

Answer (score 0):

After your computer boots, Linux runs whatever is in your system's crontab file. Cron is a program that scheduls commands, programs or scripts to run at very specific times of day. Each user has a crontab, but in this situation the system's crontab is appropriate for such a job.

You can configure cron to execute commands or programs when the system boots. So, I think this is what you mean.

In order to edit it accordingly you will want to open your system's crontab file by running the command `sudo vim /etc/crontab` Feel free to replace ``vim" with your favorite cli text editor.

Add the line (replacing appropriate things with exactly what you need, like commands, ect.) below all the others `@reboot evrouter` Note: The best idea might be to create a script and place the commands in that and run the script using crontab. It's really your choice.

Depending on your distro, you may or may not have to put who you want the command to be run as after `@reboot` Most of the time the crontab file will have some comments on the top of the file to instruct you. Of course looking at the other entries in this file will probably be the most useful to you.

Comment: Except I don't need it on boot I need it on login or the system won't have access to the config file containing the keybinds.

Comment: opening the crontab with a texteditor is a stupid way of editing the crontab. instead use crontab -e. this ensures there are no syntax errors in the corntab when closing the editor.

Answer (score 0):

By using `lightdm.conf`'s `session-setup-script` value I was able to run the command as root as expected.

```
session-setup-script=/opt/hacks/lightdm-startup
```

Meanwhile, in another folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$USER" = "j" ]
then
evrouter /dev/input/event4
fi
```

I'm still not sure why `==` didn't work in the if statement and `=` did... Bash is erratic at times.